# xpath first available value

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am developing a SW to perform CRUD operations on a registry (list of users). No DBMS is intended to use, but a lot of XML with the [Simple XML framework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/).

From the whole list a subset of the users would be selected and buffered by a java component including a memento pattern. This in order to save the state and the selected users to be able to continue from where the SW has been killed.

I want to keep the xml memento file as thin as I can so a unique index for each user came up in my mind in order to avoid to write all data for the selected users.

The user list would be like:

```
<users>
    <user id="1">
        <name> ... </name>
        <role> ... </role>
    </user>
    <user id="2">
        <name> ... </name>
        <role> ... </role>
    </user>
    ...
</users>
```

And the memento file would be like:

```
<us>
    <u>1</u>
    ...
    <u>7</u>
</us>
```

Now. I also want to keep the fragmentation as low as I can reusing the index freed by deleting users. In other words if I am using this indexes:

```
1    2    3    4
```

I add a user with index 5

```
1    2    3    4    5
```

I delete user 3

```
1    2         4    5
```

Now I want to add an other user and I wish the assigned index will be the first available one, in this case 3, thus

```
1    2    3    4    5
```

Please note that it might be that more than one index is missing so I am not considering having a variable or a data structure that keeps the history of values being freed so I could recycle them. I think it would be more efficient to compute the first index available when I need a new index.

Finally the question comes: is there a way using xPath to get the first index which lacks of the next value (sorry but I cannot find the right word to describe this kind of value)?

If none of the indexes is missing this expression will converge to the max() of them, otherwise it will return the value before the absent one.

I will update this question as details I forgot come to my mind.
Best regards,

Comment: I think what you're asking how to find the first insert point, is that right?  In your example the first one would yield 4, then 5, then 2, then 5 again?

Comment: @user3481891 Yes, exactly that!!

Comment: I don't find your question clear to me at all...

Comment: @vtd-xml-author How can I explain it in a simpler way? I want to implement an indexing system for my xml file that is reusable so when a user is deleted its index could be used again. With xPath I want to find the first usable index, or maybe metter the last before the first usable index. I think this is only a matter of expression/query. I cannot figure out how to set the path to get what I want.

Comment: what do you mean by index? What kind of indexing is that? it seems to me you are raising more unknowns with your explanation...

Comment: @vtd-xml-author By index I mean the id attribute in user element. It would be like a primary key for each user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
 count(/*[not(u[not(text())])]/u) 
+
 count(/*/u[not(text())][1]/preceding-sibling::u)
+ 1
```

---

**This can be abbreviated to just** (less readable):

```
count(
        /*[not(u[not(text())])]/u
      |
        /*/u[not(text())][1]/preceding-sibling::u
     )
+ 1
```

---

**Verification**:

Using thie following XSLT 1.0 transformation, that just evaluates the expression and outputs the result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:value-of select=
    "count(/*[not(u[not(text())])]/u) 
    +
     count(/*/u[not(text())][1]/preceding-sibling::u)
     + 1"
    />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with different "memento" XML documents such as:

**First**:

```
<us>
    <u>1</u>
    <u>2</u>
    <u>3</u>
    <u>4</u>
    <u>5</u>
    <u>6</u>
    <u>7</u>
</us>
```

**Result**: 8

**Second**:

```
<us>
    <u></u>
    <u>2</u>
    <u>3</u>
    <u>4</u>
    <u>5</u>
    <u>6</u>
    <u>7</u>
</us>
```

**Result**: 1

**Third**:

```
<us>
    <u>1</u>
    <u>2</u>
    <u>3</u>
    <u>4</u>
    <u>5</u>
    <u>6</u>
    <u></u>
</us>
```

**Result**: 7

**Forth**:

```
<us>
    <u>1</u>
    <u>2</u>
    <u></u>
    <u>4</u>
    <u>5</u>
    <u>6</u>
    <u>7</u>
</us>
```

**Result**: 3

**Fifth**:

```
<us>
    <u>1</u>
    <u>2</u>
    <u>3</u>
    <u></u>
    <u>5</u>
    <u></u>
    <u>7</u>
</us>
```

**Result**: 4

**Sixth**:

```
<us>
</us>
```

**Result**: 1

---

**Explanation**:

The XPath expression in this solution is the sum of three sub-expressions:

a) `count(/*[not(u[not(text())])]/u)`

b) `count(/*/u[not(text())][1]/preceding-sibling::u)`

c) `1`

1. The expression **a)** is the count of all `/*/u` elements, when all of them have a text child (in our specific case, a number). Here the *law of double negation* is used: For any sequence *none* of whose items doesn't *lack* a given property P, this sequence possesses the property that *all* of its items have the property P.

Read more about the *double-negation* law here: [**http://www.britannica.com/topic/law-of-double-negation**](http://www.britannica.com/topic/law-of-double-negation)  and here: [**https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation)

In this case the sequence is:

`/*/u`

and the property P is:

`u[text()]`

In other words, *all* `/*/u` elements have a child text node.

We just need to add `1` (expression **c)** ) to the number of items in this sequence and this is the solution for this particular case.

As we would see in a moment, whenever expression **a)** evaluates to non-zero, expression **b)** evaluates to zero, and vice versa.

2. The expression b) is the number of preceding siblings of the first `/*/u` element that has no text child. Again, the solution in this particular case is just to add `1` (expression **c)** )

Why cannot the two sequences **a)** and **b)** both have non-zero number of items?

This is so, because **a)** has non-zero number of items if and only if all of its items have a text child. In this case expression **b)** selects no `u` elements, because they must be preceding siblings of another `u` element that has no text child. However, there is no such element, because all of the elements in the sequence a) (and these are all `/*/u` elements) have a text child.

Comment: I am having some trouble in understanding your xPath. Can You help me understanding it? the not() function is driving me crazy.

Comment: Thank You. Now I got it. What do You think about this xPath that came in my mind this night? `/users/*[@id=count(preceding-sibling::*)+1][last()]/@id/number()`. I tested in [BaseX](http://basex.org/) and looks like that it works the way I want. I only need to increment the returned value in java.

Comment: @Gabriel, I don't see any test for "emptiness" in this expression. The first predicate is `true()` for any `/*/u` element.

Comment: @Gabriel, My solution can be abbreviated to have only a single call to `count()` : `count($A | $B) +1`

Comment: By _emptiness_ do You mean having the opening and closing tag of one element with no content? Please note that I would like to process the xPath on the user list file not on the memento file.